# Set the framerate of converted output file using ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I have the following line to convert a `.mp4` file to a `.gif` file using `ffmpeg-python`:

```
ffmpeg.input('test.mp4').trim(start=0, duration=3).output('output.gif').run()
```

It works well, but I wanted to reduce the frame rate. [At this link](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/), I could not find a way to do this. Does somebody know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg
    .input('test.mp4')
    .trim(start=0, duration=3)
    .filter('fps', fps=25, round='up')
    .output('output.mp4')
    .run()
```